# Migration to struts 2.3.32

Tags: maven, struts2

I am currently using Struts 2.3.30. I need to migrate my project to struts 2.3.32. What changes do I need to make in my pom file for a successful migration.

Pom file

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>Survey</groupId>
        <artifactId>Survey</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <name>Survey</name>
        <properties>
            <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
            <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src</directory>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </resource>
            </resources>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- put your configurations here -->
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId> <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId> 
                <version>${jackson.version}</version> </dependency> -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
                <version>0.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
                <artifactId>displaytag</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
                <artifactId>displaytag-export-poi</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
                <artifactId>displaytag-portlet</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
                <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.22</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0.GA</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ognl</groupId>
                <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.19</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.oracle</groupId> <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId> 
                <version>11.2.0.3</version> </dependency> -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.tanesha.recaptcha4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>recaptcha4j</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
                <artifactId>saaj-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- <dependency> <groupId>nl.captcha</groupId> <artifactId>simplecaptcha</artifactId> 
                <version>1.2.1</version> </dependency> -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
                <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
                <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.30</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.struts.xwork</groupId>
                <artifactId>xwork-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.30</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Comment: Change the version from 2.3.30 to 2.3.32 in both of your struts dependencies.

apache struts uses semantic versioning, so with a patch increment you shouldn't have any compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update you POM as

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.3.32</version>
</dependency>
```

it is always better to check [apache migration guide](https://struts.apache.org/docs/migration-guide.html) if you are migrating to newer version.

Answer (score 1):

As @drelliot suggested in their comment, if the project obeys SemVer, simply changing the version pin in your dependencies should be all you need to do.